# Как задать для изображения Drawing позицию в wordprocessingdocument

Tags: c#, openxml

Смотрю как генерировать ворд документы через OpenXML используя WordProcessingDocument.
Поставил себе цель вывести два изображения последовательно в одной строке. Но в результате изображения выводятся каждое с новой строки.

```
    public static void AddImageToBody(Body body, Paragraph pr, string relationshipId, UInt32Value fromLeft) {
        var element =
          new Drawing(
            new DW.Inline(
              new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
              new DW.EffectExtent() {
                  LeftEdge = 0L,
                  TopEdge = 0L,
                  RightEdge = 0L,
                  BottomEdge = 0L
              },
             // new DW.HorizontalPosition(new DW.HorizontalAlignment("right")) { RelativeFrom = DW.HorizontalRelativePositionValues.Margin },
              new DW.DocProperties() {
                  Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                  Name = "Picture 1" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
              },
              new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                  new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
              new A.Graphic(
                new A.GraphicData(
                  new PIC.Picture(
                    new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                      new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties() {
                          Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                          Name = "NewBitmapImage" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg"
                      },
                      new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                    new PIC.BlipFill(
                      new A.Blip(
                        new A.BlipExtensionList(
                          new A.BlipExtension() {
                              Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                          })
                       ) {
                          Embed = relationshipId,
                          CompressionState =
                          A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                      },
                      new A.Stretch(
                        new A.FillRectangle())),
                      new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                        new A.Transform2D(
                          new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                          new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                        new A.PresetGeometry(
                          new A.AdjustValueList()
                        ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
            ) {
                DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                //DistanceFromLeft = fromLeft,
                DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U
            });

        body.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
    }

    public static void AppendExistingDocument(string path) {
        using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true)) {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
            Body docBody = new Body();
            docBody.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("AppendText"))));
            mainPart.Document.Append(docBody);
            ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
            ImagePart imagePart1 = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
            Image img = GetBarcode();
            Image img1 = GetQR();
            using (MemoryStream ms = (MemoryStream)ToStream(img, ImageFormat.Jpeg)) {
                imagePart.FeedData(ms);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms1 = (MemoryStream)ToStream(img1, ImageFormat.Jpeg)) {
                imagePart1.FeedData(ms1);
            }

            var pr = new Paragraph();
            DrawingManagerClass.AddImageToBody(docBody, pr, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), 0);
            DrawingManagerClass.AddImageToBody(docBody, pr, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart1), 2000);
            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }
    }
```

В рамках двух изображений генерирую бар код и QrКод. Изменение параметров DistanceFromLeft, DistanceFromRight не меняют расположение. Пробовал задавать HorizontalAlign по правой стороне, тоже результата не дало. В примерах видел использование DW.Anchor вместо DW.Inline. Но при использовании первого у меня ломается документ и перестает открываться. Пробовал так же задать SimplePosition, что тоже не возымело результата.
У меня на данный момент есть идея задать таблицу с transparent гранями, и вставлять изображения в ячейки.  Но возможно есть вариант попроще.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ, нужно добавлять следующий параграф в Parent ноду.

```
        Paragraph pr1 = DrawingManagerClass.AddImageToBody(mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
        Paragraph pr2 = DrawingManagerClass.AddImageToBody(mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart1));
        pr1.AppendChild(pr2);
```